# WebBrowser getting error while navigate to url

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to create a web scraper to programmatically search and display shipment information from GLS website. I used the same function with another shipment company's site without getting any issue.

The problem is, when the `WebBrowser1.Navigate(URL)` is called, it returns a blank html page.

This is the error: [image: WebBrowser error]

Translation: "Web page exploration cancelled"

This is my code:

```
Private Function SearchShipment(ByVal indexCodiceSpedizione As Integer) As Boolean
    Try
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.gls-italy.com/it/servizi-per-destinatari/ricerca-spedizione")
        'I got the error here
        WaitForPageLoad()
        'Stuff to insert shipment code inside the website and search for infos
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

**N.B.** The `WebBrowser1` gave me the same error also on "www.gls-italy.com" but it works perfectly with other websites.

Comment: Do you need to targer .Net 3.5? It works fine with more recent versions of the control.

Comment: @Jimi it worked fine with other url like "google.com". Is it possible that "gls-italy.com" isn't a genuine html page but it is generated from some scripts? (e.g. php)

Comment: Important sites, like google.com, have a number of "templates" to support older browsers, even deprecated ones. The site you're connecting to doesn't try much to be retro-campatible (secure transactions - UE rules and privacy - don't allow it anyway). All its templates are script-generated. Also the action-buttons. Do you have a practical reason to be stuck with .Net 3.5? Try setting `ScriptErrorSuppressed = True` and see whether something comes out.

Comment: @Jimi I'm using win xp at work. don't blame me...

Comment: `ScriptErrorSuppressed` was set to True, so nothing to do here?

Comment: Just asking informations that anyone else can use to offer you a solution. If that's what it is, then it's useful to know it. I'll see what's what with a .Net 3.5 control. But I can't test it on WinXP (or maybe yes, I have to check this out). Also, check the [Gecko (FireFox) respository](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/), maybe you can find a version that fits.

Comment: I tested it on Windows 7 (the oldest I have at this time) with .Net 3.5 (WebBrowser Control version 2.0.50727.5491). It works without problems. But the underlying Activex object is not the same as WinXp. There's a good chance that the site has deprecated some versions of IE. You could try to fake some different User-Agent header.

Comment: I did some research on the gls website and it use ASP.NET framework. Probably the pages are .asp

Comment: For the address you provided, the server is Apache.

Comment: Try with these initialization strings: `WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.gls-italy.com/it/servizi-per-destinatari/ricerca-spedizione", "", Nothing, "User-Agent: Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 6.1; WOW32; Trident / 7.0; rv: 11.0) like Gecko")`.

Comment: Nothing, same error as always. I think I'm going to give up and tell my boss to update the OS. I'm the only one in the office that still use xp. evrybody is on win7. Thanks for the help Jimi, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I figured out that on `.NET 3.5` the WebBrowser isn't able to run PHP, asp.net and JS. So for me at the moment there isn't any possible solution.